# best way to handle the input data in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some input data that is user configurable, so i do not want to hard code it. Like the data path, result path etc.

Can you please suggest the best way to handle this data? Should i keep them in an excel or notepad and then read at run time? Or is there a better way to handle it?

Thanks

Comment: you want database? use sqllite ...

Comment: How often you think this data will be changed?

Comment: All this data is constant once the execution starts. Like the paths, some constant variables, environment details, login details etc. Currently I have hard coded these values in my scripts. I am looking for the best practice methods to handle this data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do it.

**Configuration file**

You can store configuration in separate file in YAML, JSON, INI or any other format. There are a lot of tools and libraries for parsing and loading such configurations. Take a look on [this article](https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/). Such approach is good for rarely changed configuration like services credentials, but it's not really good for configuration that changes very often.

**Environment variables**

Also, you can store configuration inside environment variables. Take a look on [py-env-config](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-env-config). You can hard-code default configuration values but allow user to override them using environment variables.

**Script arguments**

If you are writing a script, you can always pass all configuration as command-line arguments/options. [Manuals](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html). Such approach is good of configs that changes very often (almost every script execution).

---

**EDIT**

I'll suggest you to use configuration file for this constants.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what i was looking for.